# Why does Google Chrome recalculate styles when document title is changed?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

When the JS sets `document.title` property, Chrome (version `32.0.1700.107 m` on Windows 8.1) invalidates the styles and forces style recalculation.

Is there any meaningful reason for this? Or it's just a bug?

Check out this [JS Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/B8KfD/1/show/) ([source](http://fiddle.jshell.net/B8KfD/1/))

Comment: There are tons of events causing style recalculation all the time. I wouldn't consider this a bug, so much simply the way things are.

Comment: But is there any scenario when the change of the title affects page layout?